# Winston is not writing logs for my Heroku MERN app although it works fine locally

Tags: node.js, heroku, logging, winston

I have a MERN app -- React frontend, Express/Mongoose backend -- that works fine locally.  I deployed the backend to Heroku, the frontend to Surge and Winston no longer functions correctly. 
That is: it is not writing the log files at all, although it does so perfectly locally (localhost).

The Node version on Heroku is 8.11.4, whereas locally (MacOS) it's 10.8.0. And Heroku is being called through https rather than my localhost, which is running http.  Those are the only differences I see.

I tried specifying `__dirname`, tried remove a folder reference (that is, putting the files inside a directory `logs`, but no log files are being written anywhere.

My logger module is the following

```
const {createLogger, format, transports} = require('winston');
const {combine, timestamp, align, colorize, printf} = format;

const path = require('path')

const myFormat = printf(info => {
  return `${info.timestamp} [${info.level}: ${info.message}]`;
});


const logger = createLogger({
  level: 'debug',
  format: combine(
    colorize(),
    timestamp(),
    align(),
    myFormat
  ),
  transports: [
     new transports.File({maxsize: 500000, filename: path.join(__dirname,'logs/error.log'), level: 'error'}),
    new transports.File({maxsize: 500000, filename:  path.join(__dirname,'logs/combined.log')})
  ]
})

module.exports = logger
```

Again, the frustrating thing is it all works perfectly locally.  Thanks for any help in tracking this down!

Comment: Hi Cerulean, 
Were you able to resolve the issue.
I'm facing he same issue when app runs from the server, but on local it is able to write logs on server.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's been long enough ago I can't remember....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku hasn't local storage. Use mail transport to get errors from a server. Or You can use Heroku services for monitoring your app. Like: [Addons-Loggers](https://elements.heroku.com/addons)

Comment: Thanks, but I spoke to a more senior developer here (who also doesn't know why this isn't working) and he said he can write files to Heroku perfectly fine -- that is, there's no prohibition on writing locally.  So I don't think that's it.

Comment: @Cerulean Yes, you can write files to heroku without problem, but they will be removed once the app restarts, which is once every 24h with some random minute variations. So we should somehow transfer these logs periodically. There is always a risk of losing some data. Have you managed to solve your issue? I'm having the same problem with heroku and winston.

Comment: @OmarOmeiri -- sorry, the problem was from years ago, I don't remember if or how I solved it...

Answer (score 1):

```
const logger = winston.createLogger({
  transports: [
    ...

    // Add following code for getting logs in console as well
    new winston.transports.Console(),
  ]
});
```

Comment: Please always describe what you are doing in your answer. It should be updated or removed. Read [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before you provide more answers ^^